# jquery variable as method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery/JS setup. It works fine but I'm curious if there's a way to shorten it. I've tried a few different ways but I keep getting unassigned function errors. Is this just not possible yet?

```
switch(loadtype){
case 'html':
    ajaxcon.html(ret);
    break;
case 'prepend':
    ajaxcon.prepend(ret);
    break;
case 'append':
    ajaxcon.append(ret);
    break;
}
```

Is there a way that I could do this instead?

```
ajaxcon.loadtype(ret);
```

Comment: yes: `ajaxcon[loadtype](ret);`

Comment: For more info regarding @dandavis 's answer [Read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

Comment: That is fantastic info - thank you both!